# Button color change when untouched

Tags: html, angularjs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body ng-app="">

<p>Dummy form</p>

<form name="myForm">
<input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" required />

<div ng-show="myForm.myInput.$untouched">
<input  type="button" ng-click="deleteRow($event,name)" value="Remove" class="btn" >
</div>
<div  ng-show="myForm.myInput.$valid">
<input type="button"  ng-click="deleteRow($event,name)" value="Remove" class="btn btn-primary" ></div></form>

</body>
</html>
```

When the inputs are touched I'm trying the change the remove button color.I tried with if else,it was not working.So, used ng-show where I'm getting two buttons and the one button with changed color is working only when I click outside the form.Can anyone help?

Comment: `if else loop` there is no such thing

Comment: I said I tired with if else loop(angular) like this ,<div ng-if="myForm.myInput.$untouched">
<input  type="button" ng-click="deleteRow($event,name)" value="Remove" class="btn" >
</div>
<div  ng-else="myForm.myInput.$valid">
<input type="button"  ng-click="deleteRow($event,name)" value="Remove" class="btn btn-primary" ></div>

Comment: Haha.Got it :) Edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of using the [ng-class directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to change the class when the input is valid:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body ng-app="">

<p>Dummy form</p>

<form name="myForm">
  <input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" required />

  <input  type="button" ng-click="deleteRow($event,name)"
          value="Remove" class="btn"
          ng-class="{'btn-primary': myForm.myInput.$valid}" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When the input is empty, the <kbd>Remove</kbd> button is gray. When the input is valid the `btn-primary` class is added to the button, changing its color to blue.

Comment: That's great :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-class to determine the colour of the button:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-untouched"
  ng-class="{'coloured': myForm.myInput.$touched }" />
```

Then only when the myInput field is 'touched', will the colour of that particular button change. I know this seems opposite of what you wanted, but, by default all fields are untouched. So if you make that the default (.btn-untouched) it will be there all ready and change colour when it becomes touched. Then you'll only need one button because you can stack the ng-class options, for example:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" required />
  <input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput1" required />

  <input type="button" class="btn btn-untouched"
    ng-click="deleteRow($event, name)"
    ng-class="{'coloured': myForm.myInput.$touched, 'complete': myForm.myInput.$valid }"
    value="Remove"
    id="removeButton" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you do the same in my codes?  I'm missing your logic .

Answer (score 0):

Do it with ng-click

```
<input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" ng-click="ChangeColor()"required />

<input  type="button" ng-click="deleteRow($event,name)" value="Remove" ng-class="{'btn-warning': started, 'btn-danger': !started}" >
```

Inside your controller

```
$scope.started = false;
$scope.ChangeColor=function(){
$scope.started = true;
}
```

Comment: Yeah,I'm try to do this without touching my controller file. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Try this with only a single button and change class by ngclass

```html
<div>
<input ng-class="{'btn-primary':myForm.myInput.$valid}" type="button"  ng-click="deleteRow($event,name)" value="Remove" class="btn btn-primary" ></div>
```